# InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to write a file and then read it again.

My write code:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
try
{
    Object myObject;
    fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Foo","Bar.log"));

    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(myObject);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        oos.close();
        fout.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My reader:

```
FileInputStream input;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Foo\\Bar.log"));
    MyFile parsedObject = MyFileFormat.MyFile.parseFrom(input);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I'm getting this exception on the parser:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidEndTag(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:94)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You've tagged this "protobuf-net", but that can't be correct, it only runs on .Net.

Comment: The most likely thing I can think here is that you've overwritten a file with a *smaller* file, without truncating it - thus leaving garbage at the end. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use java's `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize your object, but using some custom de-serialization with guava involved? 
If you use `ObjectOutputStream` to write stuff, you should use [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to read it. Also, your example does not make any sense. You never initialize `myObject` variable in serialization snippet, this code will simply not compile.

Comment: you're right. myObject variable was a mistake I made adapting my code to expose here, but I guess you figured it out anyway :p sry and thanks